# Json data and html table

Tags: json, foreach, html-table

I have this structure:

HTML part:

```
<table id="table_div" class="table table-striped table-condensed"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

JS part:

```
var data = json_response['data'];

  $("#table_div").html('<thead><tr><td>TIMESTAMP</td><td>VALUE</td></tr></thead>');

  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#table_div > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + value + '<td></tr>'); 
  });
```

Now, my vector data, taken from the java console, is this for example:

```
{"data": [[1348754599, 0.0], [1348754639, 0.0], [1348754680, 0.0], [1348754721, 0.0], [1348754761, 0.0], [1348754802, 0.0], [1348754842, 0.0], [1348754883, 0.0], [1348754924, 0.0], [1348754964, 0.0], [1348755005, 0.0], [1348755045, 0.0], [1348755086, 0.0], [1348755126, 0.0], [1348755167, 0.0], [1348755208, 0.0]]}
```

And at this moment the result is that the timestamp and the value are toghether under TIMESTAMP, but column VALUE is empty.

```
TIMESTAMP   VALUE
```

1348756790,0
1348756830,0
1348756871,0
1348756911,0
1348756952,0
1348756992,0
1348757033,0

How I can i do to have

```
Timestamp Value
12876      0
129487     1
```

Thank you very much!

****EDIT****

This is the html generated now:

```
<table id="table_div" class="table table-striped table-condensed"><tbody><tr><td>TIMESTAMP</td><td>VALUE</td></tr><tr><td>1348760408,0</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1348760448,0</td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was bogus. I misremembered how `$.each()` works.

Your original code is correct except that you're not breaking each element part into its timestamp and value components. I think this code will do what you want:

```
  $("#table_div").html('<thead><tr><td>TIMESTAMP</td><td>VALUE</td></tr></thead>');

  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#table_div > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + value[0] + '</td><td>' + value[1] +'</td></tr>'); 
  });
```

Comment: It don't works, but I'm not sure on the structure of my json vector. In the response to the request of the page, from the developer console, I have this vector `{"data": [[1348757520, 0.0], [1348757560, 0.0], [1348757601, 0.0], [1348757641, 0.0]]}` but if I print the data variable in the html page I have this: `1348757520,0,1348757560,0,1348757601,0,1348757641,0`

Comment: You'll need to update the question with the actual HTML that is being generated from the code I gave you so we can further analyze it.